# conditional expectation brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

$B=(B_t,t\in[0,1])$ a standard brownian motion on $[0,1]$.

For $t\in[0,1]$, we define $$\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(B_s,s\in[0,t]),$$ $$\mathcal{G}_t=\mathcal{F}_t\,\vee\,\sigma(B_1).$$
How can we show $$\mathbb{E}[B_t-B_s|\mathcal{G}_s]=\frac{t-s}{1-s}(B_1-B_s)$$

Comment: Firstly, $B_t-B_s - \frac{t-s}{1-s}(B_1-B_s) {\perp\!\!\!\perp} B_1-B_s $ (because they make a gaussian vector and their covariance is zero). Secondly, $B_t-B_s {\perp\!\!\!\perp} F_s$ ( markov property).

Answer (score 0):

(I'm changing your notations a bit, because I want to call $B$ a Brownian bridge.)

Fix $0<s\leq1$, and let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion indexed by $[0,1]$. I call the (law of the) random variable $u\in[0,s]\mapsto W_u-\frac usW_s$ a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) of size $s$. It is but the Brownian motion modified to be $0$ at $s$, by subtracting a linear function.

I claim that the "superposition" of a Brownian bridge $B$ of size $s$ and a normal variable $N$ of variance $1$ is a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$: here, superposition means the process
$$u\mapsto B_u+uN\text.$$
One can prove this fact by noting that such a process is Gaussian, and has the desired finite dimensional covariances.

Now for what you're asking: the Brownian motion $W$ can be decomposed in for independent variables (see image below):

- two bridges $B$ and $B'$ of sizes $s$ and $1-s$;
- two Gaussian variables $N$ and $N'$ of variances $s$ and $1-s$.

(To prove this, I would go the other way around and show that given such random independent variables, the "superposition" is Gaussian and has the required covariance.)

[image: Bridge decomposition]

Once this is done, we see that
$$\mathcal{G}_t = \sigma(N,N',B)$$
and so
$$
   \mathbb{E}[W_t-W_s|\mathcal{G}_s]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[B'_{t_s} + \frac{t-s}{1-s}N'\middle|\mathcal{G}_s\right]
 = \frac{t-s}{1-s}N'
 = \frac{t-s}{1-s}(B_{1-s}-B_s)\text.
$$